# Triggering TypeScript / JavaScript in Astro from React form in onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I'm experimenting with Astro and trying to create a login form on my Astro page. I want to use [MUI](https://mui.com/) components in React for my form. At the same time when the form in submitted I want to trigger `Astro.redirect('/some-page')`. I know from [the docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/) that:

> You can pass a function as a prop to a framework component, but it
> only works during server rendering. If you try to use the function in
> a hydrated component (for example, as an event handler), an error will
> occur.
>
> This is because functions can’t be serialized (transferred from the
> server to the client) by Astro.

So my question is: Is it possible to trigger a redirect in astro from a function running when a react from is submitted?

And if not, how can I redirect in from the react component?

For good measure I have included my code below:

My Astro page looks like this

```
<Layout title="Log in">
<main>
    <div class="container box">
        <LoginFormReact client:only="react"/>
    </div>
</main>
```

And this is the content of LoginFormReact:

```js
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import LoginCheckbox from './LoginCheckBox'
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import {setUser} from "../../auth/authStore";

export default function LoginFormReact() {


    return (
        <>
            <Container component={"main"} maxWidth={"xs"}>
                <CssBaseline/>
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        marginTop: 8,
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <Avatar sx={{m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main'}}>
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Sign in
                    </Typography>
                    <Box component="form" onSubmit={async (event) => {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        //Here I can do all the js stuff i want like storing the user object. 
                        //This is also where I want to call redirect and or call astro
                    }} noValidate sx={{mt: 1}}>
                        <TextField
                            margin="normal"
                            required
                            fullWidth
                            id="email"
                            label="Email Address"
                            name="email"
                            autoComplete="email"
                            autoFocus
                        />
                        <TextField
                            margin="normal"
                            required
                            fullWidth
                            name="password"
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            id="password"
                            autoComplete="current-password"
                        />
                        <LoginCheckbox/>
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            sx={{mt: 3, mb: 2}}
                        >
                            Sign In
                        </Button>
                        <Grid container>
                            <Grid item xs>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Forgot password?
                                </a>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <a href="#">
                                    {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                                </a>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: The answer depends on where your form submission will be handled. If you handle it in a React component, you can use `location.href` or `location.replace`. If you submit to a `.astro` page, that page will have access to Astro.redirect. Bear in mind .astro pages are pre-rendered, since Astro is a static site generator. The exception being if you're using Astro's API Routes feature.

Comment: @thewildandy If your comment was an answer I would accept it, I think its the answer I was looking for

Comment: let's fix that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on where your form submission will be handled. If you handle it in a React component, you can use `location.href` or `location.replace`. If you submit to a `.astro` page, that page will have access to `Astro.redirect`. Bear in mind `.astro` pages are pre-rendered, since Astro is a static site generator. The exception being if you're using Astro's API Routes feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to redirect to another page, you can use the browser's [`location` API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#example_1_navigate_to_a_new_page)

Most likely, though, you'll want to call Astro using a `fetch` call to an endpoint, sending your form's data:

```
 <Box component="form" onSubmit={async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const response = await fetch("/api/myEndpoint", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    });
}} noValidate sx={{mt: 1}}>
```

Comment: I specifically want to do it from astro so I can use Astro.redirect(). Or ideally I would like to use the navigate method from astro-spa: https://github.com/RafidMuhymin/astro-spa

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do it this way? Astro pages (i.e. those with the .astro extension and assuming you are not using Astro's API-routes feature) are rendered in advance when you build your site, so one would assume they will essentially just perform a native JavaScript navigation under the hood (i.e. location.href = '/new-url').